# Vertical select all lines in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have a document with more than 500k lines, and I need to vertically select all of these lines. It is a bit of a pain to scroll through all of them while holding alt + the left mouse button, so I was wondering if there is a shortcut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Use:

<kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> to select all

<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + L</kbd> to split the selection to individual lines

Comment: **Note:** I tried this out on 500k lines and it's *really* slow... Like up to a minute or more for each command. ( EG: for the sequence `home`, type `test1`, `end` type `test2`; it will probably take you about 5-10 minutes. I guess more or less depending on your computer )

Comment: What actions do you need to perform on each line in your document?

Comment: Genius! This is exactly what I needed, thanks so much. However, you're correct that Sublime does start choking on anything over 65k lines. I thus had to resolve to writing a UNIX script to solve my problem. However, for smaller files, this is definitely a great technique!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Ctrl+Alt+Up` and `Ctrl+Alt+Down` noted [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html).